# How can I generate a reference page for all styles in a stylesheet

Tags: css

I've been given an extensive stylesheet created by another developer, and I'm being asked to build some pages based on those styles. I'm looking for a way to output sample text in each style, such that I can provide a reference page to our design team.

Anyone know of a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of running each selector through [the Zen Coding HTML generator](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/), which generates HTML from a CSS-selector-like syntax, and just make sure that each piece of generated HTML contains some sample text/image/etc.